# Ingress 502 bad gateway only when I click login, other pages like forgot password/register work ok

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a ASPNET Core application. when i run this using docker container, it works fine end to end. Then i move the the image to Azure AKS and create a load balancer, browse the web application using IP, and get no issues. But when i create ingress, website loads, register/forget password work on home page but on login click i get 502 bad gateway error. I tried looking at logs using kubectl logs pod -follow but no error popped up.

Have already tried changing images, recreating ingress and running code locally. Error only comes when i click on login button in azure AKS, accessing it via ingress. accessing same pod using load balancer doesnt replicate issue.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: devthecrmwebsite
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: devthecrmwebsite
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: devthecrmwebsite
          image: somewhere.azurecr.io/thecrmwebsite:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: devthecrmwebsite
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http-port
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: devthecrmwebsite
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: devthecrmwebsite
  labels:
    app: devthecrmwebsite
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: devthecrmwebsite.ac2d980d4f3a4397a96b.southeastasia.aksapp.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: devthecrmwebsite
          servicePort: 8081
        path: /
```

Comment: well, how are we supposed to know what happens when you click login in your application? what should happen? what does the browser console reports? what do ingress logs report?

Comment: did you try backend:
          serviceName: devthecrmwebsite
          servicePort: 8081
        path: /(.*)

Comment: @4c74356b41 when we click on login, it goes to post login page or gives credential error. its already working. i have tested it locally, on docker container and using load balancer. browser console shows 502 response and no other detail. please confirm command to check ingress logs.

Comment: @AnassKartit yes i did. that didnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned out to be nginx settings issue. for azure aks -
- get the deployment name of default http nginx ingress controller. 
**kubectl get deployment -n kube-system**

then checked the logs of ingress controller 
**kubectl logs -f deploy/addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller -n kube-system --tail 100**

finally found a relevant error log -  **upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream**

lot of articles online for this specific issue.

Comment: since its default http ingress, i couldnt find a way to upgrade it. details are here - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40071 . i decided to remove default http routing and created a new ingress deployment with 32k buffer size and site is working now. follow this link on config changes - https://andrewlock.net/fixing-nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-error-when-running-an-ingress-controller-in-kubernetes/  . I used this repo to rollout nginx without helm - https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#azure

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using wildcard in path , and if you plan to use the code in production you would need Nginx Ingress without using http load balancer routing addon.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing

```
         http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: devthecrmwebsite
              servicePort: 80
            path: /(.*)
```

Comment: you do realize its the same nginx ingress, just packaged by microsoft?

Comment: it is not meant for production.

Comment: so? how is this related? the question is - something doesnt work. and your answer is - `its not meant for production`? :)))

Comment: I agree, my answer is included with wild card and configuration suggestion :)) I don't see why he has to write one code to test then another one to remodify for production, feel free to correct me or suggest an improvement.

Comment: same path glob would work for the `http-application-routing` addon. he doesnt need to write any code either way.

Comment: you mean path: /(.*)

Comment: ok I modified my suggested answer let's see if it solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: says default backend - 404 if i change path suggested as above. no page loads now.

Comment: @AnassKartit its not a prod environment. i am aware of aks recommendation